# Esc key not working anymore on Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard

The escape key on my work notebook (with Windows XP SP3) stopped working some days ago.

It is not a hardware problem, because:

- It happens both with the internal keyboard and an external USB keyboard
- It magically works if I use the Remote Desktop client and connect to another computer.

I tried this keyboard key test software: [link](http://www.snaphow.com/4454/test-check-if-all-keyboard-keys-are-working-or-some-dont-work).

Every key works (i.e. it becomes green when pressed) except for the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.
The only way to make it green is to press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. When I press this key combination, both the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key become green.

I've read about problems with <kbd>Esc</kbd> key and Photoshop or [Catalyst Control Center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Catalyst) (CCC). I never installed Photoshop. I have CCC, but even terminating `CCC.exe` via [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key doesn't work (and in the past I had CCC for a long time and the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key was working correctly).

I think there's something to fix inside the Windows registry... How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the cause to my problem.
The Esc key was intercepted by QZoom ([link](http://mira96.com/2009/07/19/107/)).
I changed the shortcut keys and now my Esc key works again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should check with [Autoruns](http://download.sysinternals.com/files/Autoruns.zip) if there is some strange application active. Plus, try to disable from start CCC to see if that makes the problem or not.